# Get value from function that returns a Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, html-framework-7

I'm trying to get a value of a function on Framework7, without sucess, since it returns a promise

My function:

```
function get_coordinates_by_address(address){
    app.request.json('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q='+address+'&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1','',callback).then(function (res) {
                    data = res.data;                    
                    
                    var lat = data[0].lat;
                    var lon = data[0].lon;
                    
                    var latlon = lat + " " + lon;
                    return latlon;
                    
    })
}
```

My call:

```
var coordinates = get_coordinates_by_address(address);
console.log(coordinates);
```

My console.log:

```
Promise {<pending>}[[Prototype]]: 
    Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
    [[PromiseResult]]: "40.62162084644154 -74.15137549229134"
```

How can I get `latlon` or `PromiseResult` value?

Comment: The MDN docs have very good documentation on promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which includes how to use the result they resolve to.

Comment: alternative, you can using jquery custom event to pass the response.
https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/